# Convert a method call or assignment to a function in F#

Tags: f#

I would like to use some object-oriented code in a more functional way.
My current approach has been the following:

```
let addControl (child: Control) (parent: Control) =
    parent.Controls.Add child
    parent

let setDock dock (control : Control) =
    control.Dock <- dock
    control

form |> addControl button

button |> setDock DockStyle.Fill
```

Is there a simpler way I can define these functions?

If I take the JS approach I could define something like the following:

```
const fixMethod = name => value => parent => (parent[name](value), parent)
const resumeLayout = fixMethod("ResumeLayout")
resumeLayout(true)(form)

const fixAssign = name => value => parent => ({...parent, [name]: value})
const setDock = fixAssign("Dock")
setDock(DockStyle.Fill)(button)
```

Comment: Are you trying to define the sample F# functions shorter or have them do more as the JS does? Is this fable, fabulous, winforms, or something else?

Comment: What do you mean by "simpler"? The JS code certainly doesn't seem simpler to me.  More convenient, perhaps, but also much more error-prone.

Comment: @Maslow I was hoping for a way to define the F# functions in a single line or to have a general function that converts to method style and assignment.

Comment: @glennsl I was more aiming to define the functions in a single line. I realise the syntax is slightly complicated, which is not ideal, but possibly acceptable if confined to a single location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various tricks you could do in F#, but none of those will make your code much nicer - I would say that most tricks you can do will actually only make it more complex and unidiomatic.

There is nothing wrong with writing some imperative-looking code if that's what the underlying libraries look like. F# does have a few features that make this easier - you can, for example, specify mutable properties directly when calling a constructor, so you can set `Dock` as follows:

```
let button = new Button(Dock = DockStyle.Fill)
let form = new Form()
form.Controls.Add(button)
```

Comment: The constructor syntax covers my issue with assignment, so thanks. My broader goal was finding a quicker approach to method-calling and assignment, but (as you say) it may be that I should not fight the imperative code in cases that use it (mutable objects). I'm new enough to F# to be still figuring out when to use different styles. I'll mark this as accepted unless I have other responses in the next few days.